# In Android, why does ArrayList.contains(obj) always return false?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I need to search an array for a value. I've parsed a string to an array:

`List<String> authorArray = Arrays.asList(authorIds.split(","));`

Then I attempted to find the author ID with one the user provides:

`boolean authorExists = authorArray.contains(authorID);`

I'm logging the array values and the value being passed:

```
09-19 17:15:23.101: D/authorArray(16561): [3, 22]
09-19 17:15:23.101: D/authorID(16561): 3
```

As you can see the ID is in the array. However, `authorExists` will return `false`.

Comment: The fact that the List contains Strings of numbers makes me wonder what the type of `authorID` is. i.e. If authorID is an integer, it will always return false.

Comment: make sure authorID is also a String

Comment: @teepeeSONY - Vince's comment made me realize that I was authorID was still an integer. That fixed the issue. I have a new one but it's a different issue that's not related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be working, so I assume `authorID` is not a String.

`authorArray.contains(authorID);` will always return false if `authorArray` contains Strings, but  `authorID` is not a String.

Answer (score 1):

The `contains()` method uses the `equals()` method underneath to compare objects:

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

The probable reason why you get `false` is that what you pass into `contains()` either isn't a `String` (maybe you are passing an `int`?) or is a `String` that just isn't contained inside the list